# City field not required on checkout in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout

How to make city field not required on checkout?

Answer (score 2):

Run this query in database

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `is_required` = 0 WHERE `attribute_code` = 'city';
```

this will remove required.

Comment: This is not working for magento 2.2.6.. :(

Comment: This is not working for Magento 2.3.*

Comment: Not working for Magento 2.4 either